# blackberry text box

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

how to add a text box in blackberry java ?

```
         |--------------|
         |--------------|
```

Comment: What do you mean by text box?  A pop-up text dialog or a text field on a screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the API:

[Blackberry JDE 4.3.0 API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/index.html)

Specifically you should look at the `TextField` class.  Then you should come back with specific questions relating to what you have done and how it is not working as you would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

To implement custom TextBoxField this links will help you

http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/jul_2005/creating_textbox_field.jsp

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/TextBoxField-revisited/ta-p/548410